# Kivy (MD) - How do you access class properties when you separate the Kivy classes?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Apologies if I got my terminology mixed up. I put together this example to show my problem. I want to access the text property of the label, which I put in the LabelOne class. With the .py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label.label import MDLabel


class LabelOne(MDLabel):
    pass

class LayoutEx(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'

        return Builder.load_file('figure_out_ids.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.label_one.text = 'changed'


if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

I access the text property of the label with the `on_start` method.
Now when I structure my .kv code like this:

```
LayoutEx:
    id: layout_ex

    LabelOne:
        id: label_one
        text: 'test'
        halign: 'center'
```

the `on_start` method works perfectly and I am able to manipulate label_one.text in python.
However, what I actually want to be able to do is separate the LabelOne class in the .kv file and write it like this:

```
<LabelOne>:
    id: label_one
    text: 'test'
    halign: 'center'

LayoutEx:
    id: layout_ex

    LabelOne:
```

and still be able to call the label from the `MainApp` `on_start` method, but this gives: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` error. Now from looking around the internet, I understand that I have to change `self.root.ids.label_one.text = 'changed'` into something like `self.parent1.parent2.ids.label_one.text`, but I've failed to understand what variables need to be placed in the `parent1` and `parent2` spots. I've been stuck on this all day and I hope that someone can help me understand the process here. I suspect it is my lack of fundamental python knowledge that is causing the issue. Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is no thing `self.parent1.parent2.` in kivy you can use parent.parent.... until you reach the required widget
2. the best solution for this situation is to make the id of the `LabelOne` inside the root widget and you can put all the other `LabelOne` properties in the LabelOne class like this

```py
<LabelOne>:
    
    text: 'test'
    halign: 'center'

LayoutEx:
    id: layout_ex

    LabelOne:
        id: label_one
```

and then you can access any of LabelOne propertys using `python app.root.label_one`  in the kv file and `python self.root.ids.label_one` in the `MainApp` class
you can find many solution for this but this the best one

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Although I still don't quite understand how tip number 1 actually works in Kivy, I was able to successfully restructure my main program with your second tip and code example. Thanks again!